# Get the line number for a specific word in a Docx file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, docx

is it possible to get the line number for a specific word in a Docx-File.

I have already tried the following points.

1. .NET: DocumentFormat.OpenXml

- This way I do not get any information on the line numbers

2. .NET: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

- does not work on macOS and Linux
- see also: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/402

I would be very happy about an idea.

Comment: You do realize that words are not in lines but in paragraphs, which will fill numbers of liines depending on layout and formatting..?

Comment: Yes I know that